# memory-ordering of std::atomic<T> on certain CPUs

Tags: c++, multithreading, std, cpu-cache

With std::atomic you can do atomic increments, compare-exchanges an so on. You have the option of giving one value for the memory-ordering in case of successful and unsuccessful compare-exchanges or you can give two values, one for successful and one for unsuccesssful compare and swaps. With this you can f.e. speed up releasing a mutex which only needs release-behaviour in case of a successful operation.

But the thing I wonder about is: which CPU-architecture supports such a distinction through its ISA?

Comment: ARMv8 and probably all architectures that use LL/sc I'd think.

Comment: Releasing a mutex is normally implemented using release semantics. That is actually where release semantics got its name from.

Comment: And does LL/SC mandate a possible distinction of successful and unsuccessful operations?

Comment: Is your question specifically about compare-and-swap? Are you asking basically whether there are architectures where the generated code when the two memory orderings are different is not just the same as the generated code from using one memory ordering which is the stronger of the two?

Comment: No, I'm not asking about the difference between the compare and swap with one and with two parameters but if there are ISAs with distinctions of successful and unsuccessful compare and swaps regarding the memory-ordering.

Comment: IIRC ll/sc doesn't actually perform any ordering itself [at least on the arch I'm familiar with] - its up to the wrapper (in this case std::atomic::try_xxx) to add a whatever fences it needs before and after the swap - and of course _that_ code can add whatever barriers with whatever strength it likes and can take into account whether the swap failed or not.

Comment: What is success vs. failure of a mutex release operation?

Comment: Re-reading your Q: do you specifically ask about rel? I answered about diff mem order in general, not rel specifically. I don't think you can ever avoid rel at the ISA level, and it would take crazy patterns and compiler optimizations to avoid it at the C++ level in case of failure.

Answer (score 1):

> With this you can f.e. speed up releasing a mutex which only needs
>   release-behaviour in case of a successful operation.

How would a mutex release fail?

Releasing a mutex that isn't locked is a programming error.

Pure release operations are almost never done in a conditional, acquire operations are. Reference counting is a possible exception.

> But the thing I wonder about is: which CPU-architecture supports such
>   a distinction through its ISA?

All of those where you would have unconditionally inserted a fence instruction **after** the compare-and-set.

The reference counting case, again (which might be the most common use of RMW operations outside of mutex implementations):

- only case where the count reaches 0 is remarkable
- count only need to be "reliable" in term of staying non null while there are owners
- RC implements mutual exclusion of having a legitimate reference and seeing the count reaching 0

Essentially RC is like a RW lock:

- by definition W-locking synchronizes with all R-unlock
- with W-lock priority
- when there is a thread waiting for the W lock, so that every R 
  -unlock tries to W-lock.

In that case, you would R-unlock (so release) and if a W-lock is pending, and no further R-locks are active W-(re)lock. (Yes I know the analogy makes no sense because you would not W-relock in the same thread that did the R-unlock but whatever.)

In that case you would need an acquire fence for the W-lock.

So typically any weakly ordered CPU where acquire isn't implicit on loads.

And that would matter for primitives such as RC and RW-locks where you can try convert the last R-lock to a W-lock (try lock promotion).